# Animating a label after opening app from a local notification [Swift 3.0 - Xcode 8]

Tags: ios, swift, view, notifications, viewdidappear

Im trying to animate a label from when I open my app by clicking on a local notification. If I open the app normally, the animation works, it doesn't work when opening the app from a local notification. I have a condition (Astat) that when it becomes true, the local notification is sent. But I cant seem to get the animation to work. Heres my attempt:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if Astat == true{
        animateText()}
    print("viewDidAppear")
}
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: When are you changing Astat value to true?

Comment: I have a function that runs in the background, this functions can set Astat to true (if conditions are meet). A local notification is then sent. Astat is still true. When I press on the local notification, to open my app. Astat is still true, but the text that should be animated, is not animated.

Comment: So your app is still in the foreground?

Comment: No the app is in the background when the local notification is sent. When I press the notification, it opens my app into the foreground, thats where the label is, in which I'm trying to animate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is `viewDidApear` won't be called when you enter foreground. You need to add a notification observer to make the animation work.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(animateText), name: .UIApplicationWillEnterForeground, object: nil)
}

func animateText() {
    // An example of animating your label
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0) { 
        self.label.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 50, y: 100)
    }
}
```

Remember to remove the observer when the view controller gets deinitialised.

```
deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: .UIApplicationWillEnterForeground, object: nil);
}
```